# Ruby on Rails and Security

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, owasp

Has anyone ran across any good Powerpoint presentations on how to securely develop a web application in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rory McCune](http://www.mccune.org.uk/) is a security consultant and Rails developer who gave a presentation on this topic at Scotland on Rails. You can [view the slides online](http://www.slideshare.net/raesene/web-appliction-security-scotland-on-rails-presentation). Rory blogs about the topic too.

Answer (score 4):

Peepcode has a [PDF book on Rails security](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-security-audit-pdf) - it's $9 but they have a free preview. I've bought a bunch of screencasts from these folks, and they have been great.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Ruby on Rails Security Project](http://www.rorsecurity.info/). The offer a [free book](http://www.rorsecurity.info/the-book/) about this topic.

And of course you should read the [Ruby On Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Security book was joint developed as an OWASP project http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Ruby_on_Rails_Security_Guide_V2

It would be good to have more security related materials at OWASP

Answer (score 0):

The video for Rory's Scotland on Rails presentation is also [online here](http://www.rubyinside.com/scotland-on-rails-presentations-now-online-27-awesome-videos-1799.html)